# Can't load geoJSON layer dynamically into Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

If I load some geoJSON via a JS file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="xyz.js"></script>
```

where the .js file has data such as

```
var regions = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[ ....(etc)
```

I can then use this to add it to my map, thus:

```
var newGeoJsonLayerGroup = L.geoJson(regions, {
   // do stuff
}).addTo(map);
```

And this works a treat.  However, if I want to get this data dynamically via an AJAX call, I first amned the data file to omit the "var regions = " then fetch it and try to load it like this, it fails:

```
      $.ajax({
        url: "getRegions.ashx",
        cache: false,
        type: "post",
        async: false,
        success: function (response) { 
             var regions = response;
             var newGeoJsonLayerGroup = L.geoJson(regions, {
                 // do stuff
             }).addTo(map);            
        }
      });
```

The returned data from the AJAX call (response) is as expected, so why won't it load into the map?

Answer (score 0):

OK, silly me - my AJAX response was being returned with the wrong Response.ContentType - I was using "text/plain"; changed to "application/json" and all is good :)